# Download and read web source code, illegal?

Tags: java, html

I am working on a project which generates a meaningful url, connects to it, and download its HTML source code. The program will further read the source and extracts useful info from it. Is this illegal?

Comment: Mostly possibly - Copyright.

Comment: Short answer: no. Longer answer: it depends what you do with it afterwards. Any code that's on the internet is fair game for you to read, modify, and do what you will with, but if you use some code you found in someone else's project without crediting them, that's in violation of a few different licenses that are often used out there, like the GNU/GPL.

Comment: That's basically what web browsers do...

Comment: Google would be out of business if this was illegal.

Comment: @mellamokb The example of web browsers came to my mind when my friend asked me so. I am just not sure whether extracting certain info from the source code will get me into any trouble.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By itself, there is nothing illegal happening from what you've described. But you're being very vague.

What do you mean by "generates a meaningful url"? Generates how? What determines "meaningful"?

Downloading the html given by the server at the requested url is exactly what a browser does. Nothing odd there. Browsers also read that html and build a document from it to display to a user.

What do you mean by "extracts useful info from it"?

What do you do with the resulting info?

Are you bypassing any security, or spamming the same server with massive numbers of requests? Are you doing anything that violates someone's privacy? Are you reposting any of the information you gathered without referring back to its original source?

What is it about your project that is even raising a red flag in your mind about legality?

These are the sorts of questions you should be asking yourself.

Comment: e.g. changing parameters so the webpage shows the result of query. "Extraction" I mean is extracting text from a certain class/id. I just show the data in table form, making it easier to read. The source of info is clearly stated. Just that my friend asked me and I am not so sure whether what I am doing is 100% legal.

Comment: If you ever get a bad feeling about a programming request, my first bit of advice is to trust your gut. Even things which are legal are morally questionable or wrong. Programmers are in high demand, and you will always be able to find a project you feel good about doing.

Comment: Is it one site, or many sites? What is your friend's relationship to the site(s)?

Comment: This is my own project, not a job or whatever. There is just one to two sites which contain useful info to me. It is just a casual question from my friend. He/she does not have any relationship to the sites.

Comment: Well, assuming you're not bypassing security, so far this sounds fine to me.

Comment: For sure I am not. Encouraging, nice explanation. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If this is for a personal project, then no it is not illegal in the least. If this is for a commercial product, however, I would err on the side of respecting any copyrighted content on the webpage.